# Name of the order with irreflexivity, antisymmetry and transitivity?

Tags: terminology, definition, relations, order-theory

I have an order otherwise poset aka partial order but it is irreflexive so relationships such as 1R1 and 2R2 are impossible. What is the name of this order?

Comment: It's a strict partial order.

Comment: Also called [irreflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders).

Comment: The thing I am trying to understand is the amount of relationships in a `"strict partial order"` with $n$ amount of elements. I cannot yet understand how to read this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Number_of_partial_orders). Anyway thanks for answers! Taking some time to dig deeper...

Comment: hhh - Note the fine print below the table: because of the one-to-one correspondence between a partial order and the corresponding strict partial order, "the number of strict partial orders is the same as that of partial orders" on a set with $n$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is irreflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive, then it is also known as a strict partial order. Notice however, that there is very little difference between strict partial orders and partial orders. The reflexive closure gives a bijection between strict partial orders and partial orders.

Comment: Can I also say `"proper partial order"` to mean `"strict partial order"`? +1 for the entry. I understand this [document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict) so that I can use the words strict and proper interchangeable.

Comment: Accepted because of the last line, thank you.

Comment: What if $R$ is irreflexive,asymmetric and transitive, is it still strict partial order?

Comment: Note that irreflexive and transitive is sufficient to prove the strict partial order.

Answer (score 2):

As Ittay answers, such a relation is known as a ***strict partial order***.

To read more about the relationship and distinction between a *partial order* and a *strict partial order,* see the Wikipedia entry on [partial order vs. strict partial order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_order#Strict_and_non-strict_partial_orders).

Notice that in the linked entry:  there exists a one-to-one correspondence between a partial order and the corresponding strict partial order, and so "the number of strict partial orders is the same as that of partial orders" on a set with n elements.

An example often used is relation $\leq$, which is a partial order, and $\lt$ which imposes a strict partial order.

Comment: Nice attribution and answer! +1

Comment: @hhh I'm sorry If I left out what you needed. I thought the linked section of the Wiki entry did a nice job of explaining why there exists a one-to-one correspondence between a partial order and the corresponding strict partial order, and didn't want to duplicate what was expressed nicely there.

Comment: @amWhy err both answers are great, I decided to upvote your answer and your comment and then balance for Ittay's succint answer. I just liked the way he wrote the last sentence. Thank you.

Comment: That's perfectly fine! No criticism intended...just that being accepted, then unaccepted, stings a little. But I'm a big grown-up, so I can handle it ;-)